# Converting String in Array position into position and return the order in python

Tags: python

I've been working with lists and arrays.In this task I need to return (in order) the sentence but instead of returning the sentence in order I need to return the positions the words are in, in order So here is my current code:

```
sentence = "Hello my name is Daniel, hello Daniel"
sentence = sentence.upper()
sentence = sentence.split()
list = sentence
```

which returns:

```
['HELLO', 'MY', 'NAME', 'IS', 'DANIEL,', 'HELLO', 'DANIEL']
```

but the desired out come is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4]
```

Does anyone know how I could get this outcome from the given code by adding more code to it?

Comment: In your model, both `'DANIEL,'` and `'DANIEL'` are being represented by `4`.  Do you need to strip punctuation?

Comment: @mgilson in this case punctuation does not affect the outcome, so 'Daniel,' and 'Daniel' are treated as the same and should return the same position

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to get `Daniel` not `Daniel,` so you should replace the comma or remove it.And then use index method to return the lowest index in list that obj appears.

```
sentence = "Hello my name is Daniel, hello Daniel"
sentence = sentence.replace(',','').upper()
sentence = sentence.split()


print [sentence.index(i) for i in sentence]
```

And it returns

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4]
```

Comment: thank you!!! Would this method work if the variable 'sentence' is a sentence inputted by the user?

Comment: @D.Forrester yeah.If this helps,please accept this answer.

Comment: sentence = sentence.replace(",",'"',"'").upper()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' 
this error has occur when I made sentence into a user inputted variable. do you know why? @McGrady

Comment: @D.Forrester  Make sure `sentence` is a string,and then use `split()` method.To get the input as a string,you should use `raw_input` in Python2 or `input` in Python3.